# Replace one line of a file with another line in a second file if it matches the condition

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I am here wondering that if I can read each line of `a.txt` and compare it to each line in `b.txt`. If any line in `a.txt` matches the beginning part of the line in `b.txt`, we replace the matched line with the line we found in `a.txt`. So let's say there are two lines: `alias cd /correct/path/` and `alias cd /wrong/path/sth` in `a.txt` `b.txt` respectively. Now after I execute my command I would like the lines to be all like: `alias cd /correct/path/` on both files. My own solution is to do two `while...read..` functions and use `sed -i ///` to replace the line, but I think it is very clumsy and not efficient. I am looking to be enlightened with a more clean & efficient solution. Here is my code if it helps by any chance:

````
awk 'NR==FNR { array[$0]; next } { delete array[$0] } END{for (key in array) { print key } }' a.txt b.txt > tmp
input="tmp"
while IFS= read -r line
do
    echo "$line"
    cat b.txt > n_tmp
    n_input="$n_tmp"
    while IFS= read -r n_line
    do
        if $n_line | awk '{print $1, $2}' == $line | awk '{print $1, $2}'; then
            sed -i "s/$n_line/$line/" b.txt
        fi
    done < "$n_input"
    rm -rf n_tmp
done  < "$input"
rm -rf tmp```
````

Comment: I'm pretty sure `paste`command would be suited for this task.

Comment: it would be helpful if you provided some sample input data (including lines to leave as, and linnes to be changed), and then provide the expected output/result data; also, some indication of the size (MBytes) of each file

Comment: From your example, it is very unclear when to replace a line. `alias cd /correct/path/` does **not** match the beginning of `alias cd /wrong/path/sth`. You probably don't want to match prefixes either, as the very different commands `test ...` and `time ...` share the common prefix `s`. Also, it is unclear what should happen when multiple lines "match". Your code doesn't help either in answering these questions as things like `$n_line | awk '{print $1, $2}' == $line` don't work at all. Did you even try to run it?

Comment: @Socowi Yeah I tried to run it, it complained about the `input` and `n_input` variables not being existed. And I tested the line `$n_line | awk '{print $1, $2}' == $line` it works in my terminal. The idea is to take the string in the selected file up until the second space, don't really care about if it has a prefix or not. The two files should share very similar structure with each other.

Comment: @markp-fuso The file is just something I used for testing. As you can see from the given example, it mostly contains some aliases which is meant to mimic a `.bashrc` file. There it is likely to have those aliases and what I wanted to do is to check if it is an alias and if it has the same name.

Comment: @Rfroes87 Yeah in normal ways ofc, but what i intended is to achieve this by script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few mistakes in this script and most of them are within the line: `if $n_line | awk '{print $1, $2}' == $line | awk '{print $1, $2}'; then`. First of all the way to get result from `$n_line | awk '{print $1, $2}'` is wrong as there is no action for `n_line` variable. There needs to be added an **echo** so that we can get the output of the string and the `awk` command can follow up. Secondly there is **no double quotes** for strings or whatever I was trying to get from the `$n_line | awk '{print $1, $2}'` command. Lastly, there is a **double bracket** needed to wrap around the two sides of the comparator. So in the end it should look something like this:

```
b_string=`echo "$n_line" | awk '{print $1, $2}'`
if [[ "$a_string" == "$b_string" ]]; then
```

I figured to declare the echoing part into a variable as well, it may look a bit cleaner and easier to handle. There are still some other problems with this script, but as of now I think the primary issue is solved.